# ¿Como multiplicar los valores de las mismas posiciones de dos arrays distintos en php?

Tags: php, array

Lo que quiero, es que mi documento php multiplique los valores de las mismas posiciones, este es mi arreglo:

```
Array(

[Codig] => Array
    (
        [0] => 300A
        [1] => 300B
        [2] => 300C
        [3] => 300D
    )

[Descr] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pasta Dental
        [1] => Coca-Cola T/Lata
        [2] => Raptor T/Lata
        [3] => Miel de Maple
    )

[Canti] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 1
    )

[Preci] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12.00
        [1] => 3.00
        [2] => 5.00
        [3] => 25.00
    )
```

Lo que necesito es poder multiplicar las mismas posiciones de lo que es, Canti * Preci, por ejemplo:

```
$Cantidad = ([0] => 5, [1] => 4, [2] => 2, [3] => 1);
$Precio   = ([0] => 12.00, [1] => 3.00, [2] => 5.00, [3] => 25.00);

$Resultado= ([0] => 60.00, [1] => 12.00, [2] => 10.00, [3] => 25.00);
```

Espero mi pregunta se explique bien con lo que escribí acá... Por favor necesito saber como hacer esto... Gracias de Antemano

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Como pista, recorre un array para obtener posición / valor y usa la misma posición para acceder a los otros, ejemplo: `foreach($cantidades as $posicion => $valor) {  $totales[$posicion] = /* completa la operación */ }`

Comment: Si los indices son numéricos consecutivos, te podría servir algo como: `$resultado = array_map(function($a1, $a2) {return $a1*$a2;}, $Cantidad, $Precio);` Referencia: [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas Gracias a todos por sus respuesta, pero ya he encontrado una solucion basandome en sus ayudas!!! es la siguiente:

```
<?php
//Esto es si su array lo reciben desde un form con metodo POST, 
//este POST recibe exactamente el array que puse en la pregunta.
$Codigo      = array_values($_POST['Codig']);
$Descripcion = array_values($_POST['Descr']);
$Cantidad    = array_values($_POST['Canti']);
$Precio      = array_values($_POST['Preci']);

//Este array_map, me selecciona cada indice numerico (o eso espero que haga :D),
//Y me muestra sus valores con el array_velues.
$Resultado1 = array_values(array_map(function($a1, $a2) {return $a1*$a2;}, $Cantidad, $Precio));


//Un Ciclo For que mide el tamaño de $Resultado1, con la funcion Sizeof();
For($i=0;$i<sizeof($Resultado1); $i++){

    //Prints que nos muestran cada array con su respectivo precio y cantidad.
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(var_export($Codigo[$i]));
    print_r(var_export($Descripcion[$i]));
    print_r(var_export($Cantidad[$i]));
    print_r(var_export($Precio[$i]));

    //Imprime el sub-total de nuesta multiplicacion anterior en el array, Canti * Preci
    print_r($Resultado1[$i]);   
    echo ' = ';    

    //EXTRA A MI PREGUNTA:
    //Funcion array_Sum que nos va sumando los totales de $Resultado1 para saber el Total de la compra
    $Total1 = array_sum($Resultado1);
    $Total2 = 0;

    $Total2 =+ $Total1;
}
//EXTRA A MI PREGUNTA:
//print que nos imprime el Total de la Compra.
echo '<pre>';
echo '<pre>';
echo 'el Total de la compra es: $.'; 
print_r($Total2);
```

Muchas Gracias Por su atencion!

Comment: Si es tu solución final no olvides pòr favor marcarla como aceptada

Comment: lo intente pero no me deja aun... hasta dentro de 22 horas...

Comment: En la pregunta original se entendía que era un solo array y que querías multiplicar los valores correspondientes en cada clave. Si los datos vienen separados en dos arrays es mucho más simple no entiendo qué es lo que quieres finalmente si multiplicar o sumar ¿?

Comment: queria multiplicar, el precio por la cantidad del array, para obtener sub-totales, pero lo ultimo es Extra, no era parte de mi pregunta pero lo puse por si alguien necesita la suma de los sub-totales...

Comment: Gracias Por compartir su solución a su pregunta, tambien me sirvio!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer con la ayuda de [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk-recursive.php), que te permite aplicar cierto código a cada miembro de un array asociativo.

En este caso, mediante su uso, aplicamos una lógica para buscar el *operando* y el *operador*  para hacer la multiplicación, mientras vamos guardando cada valor en un array final.

Aquí te lo dejo, he puesto comentarios en cada parte del código para que se entienda:

### Código:

<kbd>**[`VER DEMO`](https://rextester.com/YED10359)**</kbd>

```
/*
    Mediante este array identificamos
    al operando y al operador
*/
$toFind=array('Canti','Preci');

/*
    Array para guardar los resultados
*/
$finalData=array();
foreach ($mArray as $key=>$subArray) {
    /*
        array_walk_recursive aplica la lógica implementada
        en el bloque de la función a todos los miembros del array
    */
    array_walk_recursive($subArray,function($v,$k)use($key,$toFind,&$finalData){
        /*
            Verificamos si la clave actual $key
            se encuentra dentro de $toFind, que fue el array
            que usamos para identificar al operando y operador
        */
        if(in_array($key,$toFind)){
            /*
                Cuando $key sea igual a Canti agregaremos $v 
                en el índice $k del array final
            */
            if ($key===$toFind[0]) { $finalData[$k]=$v; }

            /*
                Cuando $key sea igual a Preci multiplicamos $v 
                por el valor que ya habrá en el array final
            */

            if ($key===$toFind[1]) { $finalData[$k]*=$v;}
        }
    });
}
/*
    Probamos nuestro resultado
*/
var_dump($finalData);
```

**Salida:***

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  float(60)
  [1]=>
  float(12)
  [2]=>
  float(10)
  [3]=>
  float(25)
}
```